# Foundation’s topbar isn’t working — what have I done wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, zurb-foundation

I’m trying to you use Foundation’s Topbar functionality to design my navigation, but all I’m getting right now is a totally unformatted, bulleted list. I have none of my own CSS or JS code linked right now, it’s all basic external stuff like jQuery and Foundation. I have linked all of Foundation’s Javascript and CSS files as you can see below, and my browser’s Console is reflecting that I have no errors; that all the files I’ve called in my HTML have been found. What am I missing? Why isn’t the Topbar appearing?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Page metadata. -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" />
  <title>Coding &amp; Design in INFO250</title>
  <!-- Linked CSS files. -->
  <link href="css/external/foundation.min.css" />
  <link href="css/external/normalize.css" />
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">Coding &amp; Design in INFO250</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 508</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MySQL</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
  <div class="bg-holder splash1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Coding &amp; Design</h1>
      <h3>in INFO250</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript, linked and otherwise. -->
  <script src="js/external/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/external/fastclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/external/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script>
            <script src="js/external/jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/external/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/external/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/external/foundation.topbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make a Fiddle or show us your project structure - it is probably because of bad paths to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered it wasn’t working because I hadn’t specified “rel='stylesheet’" and “type='text/css’” on the links to Foundation and Normalize CSS.